# Oracle Secure Backup (OSB) issue - "failed to read configuration data - Network is unreachable"

Tags: backup, oracle-12c

I am using Oracle 12.2.0.1 on Linux 6.8. I am using OSB to take a backup to tape.
After an unknown host name error in the backup log, I edited the /etc/hosts file and restarted the server.

After restarting, when I enter obtool in the DB server (which is a client) it says

> failed to read configuration data - Network is unreachable

Can anyone please throw me some light on this issue?

Comment: Does the machine you're on have network connectivity? Have you verified it with some pings/traceroutes?